# how to run a django project (made on linux) on windows?

Tags: django

I am new to programming and started working on Linux, now I want to switch to windows and open my project there, look at the tutorials, it is written to activate the virtual environment in the Settings / activate.bat folder. but in my project there is no such folder and such file with the extension .bat. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please download & Install interpreter from https://www.python.org/downloads/
   (make sure you are using windows 10, because previous 
   version create problems)
2. Download pycharm professional addition (if you have university account) other wise go for community https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/
3. Click for Django project
4. Set the interpreter
5. Go to. manage.py task
6. Run command migrate
7. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing get all the requirements like the library you installed through pip inside 
   a txt file by writing this command pip freeze > requirements.txt.
2. Get only the source folder where you made the project and app.
3. Create a folder.
4. Create an environment inside the folder. (virtualenv name_of_the_env)
5. Go inside the env you created and activate the Script. (.\Scripts\activate)
6. Copy the source folder inside the env and either you can install all the library 
   manually using pip or you can use requirement.txt that you have created to install the 
   library by writing this command pip install -r requirement.txt.

You need python and pip installed to work